# tracked overlay image on live video

Tags: video-sequence-editor, image

I tried transparent overlay image of eye on my eye surgery video on the VLC media. Of course the image was stationery and the eye in video was mobile .Can I make a 2D or 3D image overlay on the video where the image of eye which corresponds to the eye in the video and constantly keeps overlapped exactly on the underlying video ? I am an Eye surgeon by profession but like to develop things which help me serve my patients better. Thank you in advance .
Dr Dharmesh Bhuptani

Comment: In blender this can be done on recorded media, as a video file or image sequence. For an implementation on real time blender is not the right tool.

Comment: Pray then which software or technique do you suggest for the same sir?

Comment: I am extremely sorry for the caps. Actually I have to keep it on Caps moe for my electronic patient software. I have rectified the mistake

Comment: There are a number of implementations of computer vision using OpenCV you would need to do a search for that.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will do the same. It was very gracious of you. Regards